# error en un activity, android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Mi problema es el siguiente tengo una app en android studio, se puede hacer pequeñas publicaciones con un titulo, una imagen y una descripcion, despues se puede visualizar en una lista en un activity, tambien se puede crear usuarios y autenticarlos, ayer intente colocar un splash screem, pero ahora las listas que deberia mostrar, ya no puedo verlas, no se que paso, como mencion uso firebase para los datos.

intente poner el activiy con intent filter para que inicie de primero , pero se cierra la app, con los demas si funciona bien.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta funciona bien 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la que da error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me sale esto en el logCat, no le entiendo sinceramente
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola no se ve todo el error, mejor copialo y pegalo :D

Comment: Agrega el PostDetailActivity onCreate que es donde se encuentra el error

Comment: En la actividad haces referencia a un objeto nulo específicamente el ActionBar, pon el código de la actividad por favor para ver que es lo que sucede.

Comment: Agrega la información que te sugiere la comunidad, de otra forma las causas para el error pueden ser diversas.

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo *PostDetailActivity.java* en la linea 70

reemplaze

> `getActionBar().hide();`

por

> `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Cuando uses *AppCompatActivity* algunos metodos cambian, con respecto a una Activity del lenguage base